# In Liquibase, how do I represent a view that uses common table expressions(CTE) for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, liquibase

I would like to put my views in liquibase but I am struggling to figure out how to represent the CTE.  The view definition is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.all_parts
AS
WITH parts AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT master.part_number
       FROM public.master
    UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT subassembly.part_number
       FROM public.subassembly
    UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT subassembly.parent_pnum
       FROM public.subassembly
    ), parents AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT subassembly.parent_pnum
       FROM public.subassembly
    )
SELECT parts.part_number,parts.parent_pnum
 FROM parts;
```

Comment: I typically create views using `<sqlFile>` in Liquibase (using `runOnChange="true"` in the `changeSet`), then you only need to put the above into a SQL script and include it from your changeLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @a_horse_with_no_name worked.  The only issue now is how to manage updates since you would essentially have to have new versions of the view in different files, which kind of defeats the purpose of putting them in version control.

Comment: If the SQL script (and the Liquibase Changelog) is stored under version control (git, svn) you don't need to create a new version of the SQL script.

Comment: I ended up making a changeset just for views and procedures, stored them all in separate files, and set it to runAlways="true".